# C++ error: no matching function for call to function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function template that extracts data from an image and copies it to a smaller array (which I call a `Patch`) the template function is called `copyPatch`. It is defined as:

```
template <class DestType, class SrcType, class Transformation>
bool copyPatch(Patch<DestType> &patch, 
               ImageData<SrcType>* src_data, 
               size_t src_ul_pix, 
               size_t src_ul_line)
```

Note: the `Transformation` parameter allows me to pass in a class that performs some transformation on the data. I call the template function as follows,

```
copyPatch<float, uint8_t, StraightCopy>(m_patch_data, m_data.t8u,
                                        ul_pix, ul_line)
```

where `m_patch_data` is of type `Patch<float>` and `m_data.t8u` is a member of a union defined as follows:

```
union {
    ImageData<uint8_t>*     t8u;
    ImageData<uint16_t>*    t16u;
    ImageData<int16_t>*     t16s;
    ImageData<uint32_t>*    t32u;
    ImageData<int32_t>*     t32s;
    // A bunch more of these
    void*               tvoid;
} m_data;
```

When I compile this I get the following error (that I've doctored a bit):

```
error: no matching function for call to:

copyPatch(Patch<float>&, ImageData<unsigned char>*&, size_t&, size_t&)’
copyPatch<float, uint8_t, StraightCopy>( m_patch_data, m_data.t8u, ul_pix, ul_line);
                                                                                          ^
note: candidate is:

template<class DestType, class SrcType, class Transformation> 

bool copyPatch(Patch<T>&, ImageData<SrcType>*, size_t, size_t)
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

To me, I don't see why the function didn't match.  The only possible reason I can see is that for the 2nd parameter it wants a pointer (which is what I thought I was passing), but the calling code seems to be passing a reference to a pointer.

Compiler is g++ 4.8.1.

As pointed out in the comments the problem possibly with my Transformation (StraightCopy) which is defined as follows:

```
template<class Dest, class Src>
class StraightCopy {
public:
    Dest operator()(Src s) { return static_cast<Dest>(s); } 
};
```

I missed passing the parameters to my StraightCopy class.

Comment: Is that the complete error? often gcc tells a bit about why that candidate did not match

Comment: Don't specify function template parameters. Let them be deduced. Just `copyPatch<StraightCopy>(m_patch_data, m_data.t8u, ul_pix, ul_line);` (and reorder the arguments).

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not possible for `Transformation` though

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes. That should go at the front, I suppose.

Comment: Otherwise it shouldnt be hard to provide the community with a single TU of code that exihibits the same behaviour when people try to compile it for themselves.

Comment: Something tells me you're not showing your real code. Go and make a *small*, representative example that reproduces the problem. I guarantee you that in doing so you'll find your error.

Comment: PlasmaHH.  I left off the template/argument deduction/substitution failed bit (answer to your first comment) I've edited it to add it in. Regarding a minimal compilable example, I tried to create one that was equivalent, but for some reason it worked!

Comment: @CraigDillabaugh: Then your mission is to find the difference. Also you seem to have cut of the error yet again, the line ending with `:` seems to indicate that gcc is telling more.

Comment: My wild guess btw. is that `StraightCopy` is not a type. If that is the case, you owe me a beer.

Comment: PlasmaHH, I guess I owe you a beer - how do I send it over the internet ....   StraightCopy was defined, but it is also parameterized (and I left off the types).  I've edited my original post to describe StraightCopy.  How do I accept your answer, or I should I post my own answer and mark it as correct solution (Now I see).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PlasmaHH for pointing me in the right direction. My transformation type (StraightCopy) needed parameters.  So my call looks like:

```
copyPatch<float, uint8_t, StraightCopy< float, uint8_t > >( m_patch_data, m_data.t8u, ul_pix, ul_line);
```

Isn't that beautiful :o)

Comment: See, this is why its useful to see things as they are: `StraightCopy` is not a type, its a template. Instantiating it with parameters creates a new type. A useful compiler (clang maybe?) would have errord out with : "expected a type, got a template, wtf?"